# Getting the record type id using Describe doesn't compile

Tags: apex, record-type

I have used the below method of getting RecordTypeIds for any record many times and it has worked for me-

```
Id RTid = Order.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Export Order').getRecordTypeId()
```

wierdly, it's throwing an error today for a specific class whereas in another class is getting compiled-

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid field sobjecttype for SObject Order at
>   line x column y

The same method executes well in Anonymous Apex.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong.

For the time being I've changed my code to

```
Id RTid = Schema.SObjectType.Order.RecordTypeInfosByName.get('Export Order').RecordTypeId;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual cause of this sort of problem is a local variable or class member or class that is also called `order` (case doesn't matter) taking precedence over the type name.

A way to avoid that is to add the `Schema` prefix:

```
Id RTid = Schema.Order.sObjectType.getDescribe()...
```

(or change the name of the local variable or class member or class).